# "hygiene" and "hygeine" tags should be merged

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There are both, a hygiene and a hygeine tag.
Please merge those two tags into the correctly spelled one!

I hope this is the right place to bring this up, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 7):

Done.  And yes, this is exactly the right place to bring this up.